# Oreo AlarmManager not working in Background

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I want to start a Notification Service with an AlarmManager. However, it doesn't alyways work, when swiped the app in the recent tasks layer. I have also tried out JobIntentService and JobService with the propriate entries in the Manifest, everything resulted in the same problem: The Notification or also startActivity() don't get called (sometimes!, maybe when in doze mode?) after I closed the app.

Now, I thought to maybe go back to the AlarmManager, as it seems to work for other people here.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        {
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlertReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 1, intent, 0);

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 23)
            {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeForAlarm, pendingIntent);//Alarm with setExact and AlertReceiver should be better than the old Alarm Manager
            }
            else
            {
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeForAlarm, pendingIntent);//Alarm with setExact and AlertReceiver should be better than the old Alarm Manager

            }
          }
        else
        {
            final AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Service_Notification.class);

            PendingIntent startPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
            alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeForAlarm, startPendingIntent);
        }
```

This is my AlertReceiver for Versions above KitKat (I also tried extends BroadCastReceiver)

```
public class AlertReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, Service_Notification.class));
    }
}
```

So, what can I do now? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. It seems the policy for background task has been changed a lot since Oreo. You could check the [WorkManager](https://developer.android.google.cn/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager.html?hl=en) in Jetpack. It simplifies a lot the use cases across different OS version.

```
OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder ob = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(YourWorker.class)
    .setConstraints(constraints)
    .setInitialDelay(delayed, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .addTag(yourWorkerTag);
WorkManager.getInstance().beginUniqueWork(orderTag, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, ob.build()).enqueue();
```

And then start your Notification Service in `YourWorker`. It's done!

Comment: But work manager isn't a good solution when we wants fire the alarm at exact time.